# File `pdfcol.sty' not found

Tags: packages

Here is a problem that

[image]

I don't know how to find "pdfcol.sty". Could any one help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compalable tex code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: check for updates. pdfcol has been splitted out of the oberdiek bundle a few weeks ago and is now in its own package.